# Не ставится Windows 7 никакими способами, перепробовали всё

Tags: windows, windows-7, установка

На компьютер после покупки установили Windows 7, всё идеально работало, после этого установили Windows 10, работала в течении 1 года, не понравилась, решили установить Windows 7 обратно, но она не устанавливается, при установке пишет "Waiting USB disks to initialize".
Пробовали на разных флешках писать, разные образы включая x64 и x32, писали программами WinSetupFromUSB и Rufus разными версиями и всеми способами, сбрасывали BIOS, вытаскивали CMOS, много раз пытались, ничего не вышло.

Компьютер слабый, иногда глючит.

DEXP Aquilon O175 Celeron

Страница в интернет магазине (Его сняли с продажи):
https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/771e50d0752e3330/pk-dexp-aquilon-o175/characteristics/

Характеристики компа:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BWWQmuel-9vDb5ZTIzIKVnzMSbI8aZX1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Записывай образ диска на флешку через [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) должно всё хорошо пойти!
Только нужно выбрать правильно схему раздела GPT или MBR
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это не сработает, используя уже созданную загрузочную флешку сделайте так как говорят в этом видео [Ссылка на видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9uvJECzSdTA). 
Нужно использовать утилиту "*Windows.Loader.v2.2.2*" 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написано же - ПИСАЛИ УЖЕ через руфус!

Comment: щас попробую mbr или gpt, расскажу в комменте удалось или нет

Comment: Может образ iso кривой? Попробуйте другой образ.

Comment: образов много пробовали, у меня в руфусе только MBR

Comment: а в версии 2.18 есть gpt

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GmNCitO8rE6_L4VT7VV-HSM2dEle-2i5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: попробую GPT для компов с UEFI

Comment: Скачайте последнюю версию Rufus я давал вам ссылку в посте.. Это их официальный сайт. И попробуйте выбрать между  mbr или gpt.. Если не поможет пишите.

Comment: Вообще не загружается ни с флешки ни с диска - синий экран

Comment: попробую новым руфусом с сайта

Comment: загружается с флешки но пишет не найден необходимый драйвер

Comment: Я дополнил ответ в статье. Прочитайте его.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!!!!!! всё заработало!!!!!!!!!!!!!!